# How to cast a char* to string in D?

Tags: string, pointers, casting, char, d

I have a standard char pointer which im trying to cast to a string.

```
// string to char*
char *x = cast(char*)("Hello World\0");

// char* to string?
string x = cast(string)x;
string x = cast(immutable(char)[])x;
```

Error!

Any ideas how to cast a char* to a string in D?

Comment: pst: string literals already have `\0` appended

Comment: Why is that if the length is already known through the fat pointer? For C compatibility?

Comment: @Daevius, Yes, this way when you call into a C function you don't have to wrap all your string literals with toStringZ.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `std.conv.to` to convert from `char*` to `string`.  Use `std.string.toStringZ` to go the other way.

```cpp
import std.string;
import std.stdio;
import std.conv;

void main()
{
    immutable(char)* x = "Hello World".toStringz();
    auto s = to!string(x);
    writeln(s);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you know the exact length you can do this:

```
immutable(char)* cptr = obj.SomeSource();
int len = obj.SomeLength();

string str = cptr[0..len];
```

For some cases (like if the string contains `\0`) that is needed.

Comment: I think `len` should be of type `size_t`.