# D2, How to convert immutable(char)* to string?

Tags: c, string, char, d

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to cast a char* to string in D?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811806/how-to-cast-a-char-to-string-in-d)

One can use Phobos std.toStringz() in D2 to convert a string to a 
C compatible immutable(char)*. toStringz() will assure that the resulting pointer will reference a zero terminated string.

My question is how does one convert in the other direction..
Given a char* pointer how does one convert/cast such to become a well formed string object in the D2 language?

found answer here: [How to cast a char* to string in D?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811806/how-to-cast-a-char-to-string-in-d)